# How to create a list of switch case statements in doxygen?

Tags: doxygen

I need to comment/document some existing code. To do that I use Doxygen, which works pretty fine. But now I have a question:
I have a code, that reacts to commands, received via a user interface. Those commands are not processed in seperate functions, but in ONE function, using a switch case statement. So basically the code looks like this:

```
switch (command[0])
{
    case 'a': do_something(command[1]);
    case 'b': do_something(command[2]);
    case 'c': do_something_else(command[3]);
    case 'd': do_something_else(command[4]);
}
```

I want to create some kind of list, which gives an overview over all cases and clicking on a case leads to a detailed description.
What Doxygen tool would you recommend for that task????

Thanks....
Sebastian

Comment: Which doxygen version? Which settings used?

Answer (score 0):

When documenting documenting the code for this switch statement I would go for something like:

```
/// \file

/// the fie
void fie(void)
{
  switch (command[0])
  {
    /// case a work
    case 'a': do_something(command[1]);
    /// case b work
    case 'b': do_something(command[2]);
    /// case c work
    case 'c': do_something_else(command[3]);
    /// case d work
    case 'd': do_something_else(command[4]);
  }
}
```

the following does work as well

```
/// \file

/// the fie
///
/// depending on the value of `command[0]` the following actions are performed:
/// case a work
/// case b work
/// case c work
/// case d work
void fie(void)
{
  switch (command[0])
  {
    case 'a': do_something(command[1]);
    case 'b': do_something(command[2]);
    case 'c': do_something_else(command[3]);
    case 'd': do_something_else(command[4]);
  }
}
```

Note due to missing information I tested with doxygen 1.8.20 only.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, Albert.  I am thinking about \defgroup or \xrefitem but I don´t get those to work properly. It should look like the linked list here: https://www.doxygen.nl/manual/commands.html

Comment: I am also using Doxygen 1.8.20

Comment: The list you are referring to is a so called `\secreflist` list  with as items: `\refitem`.

Comment: Oh, I see. I was using that in a wrong way. Do I have to create (and sort) that list manually? I expected the ```\refitem``` command doing that for me....